# How to select rows in dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have an emails dataframe in which I have given this query:

```
williams = emails[emails["employee"] == "kean-s"]
```

This selects all the rows that have employee kean-s. Then I count the frequencies and print the top most. This is how it's done:

```
williams["X-Folder"].value_counts()[:10]
```

This gives output like this:

```
attachments                   2026
california                     682
heat wave                      244
ferc                           188
pr-crisis management            92
federal legislation             88
rto                             78
india                           75
california - working group      72
environmental issues            71
```

Now, I need to print all the rows from emails that has X_Folder column equal to attachments, california, heat way etc. How do I go about it? When I print values[0]  it simply returns the frequency number and not the term corresponding to it (tried printing it because if I'm able to loop through it, Ill just put a condition inside dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for values of index:

```
df = williams[williams["X-Folder"].isin(williams["X-Folder"].value_counts()[:10].index)]
```

Or:

```
df = williams[williams["X-Folder"].isin(williams["X-Folder"].value_counts().index[:10])]
```

If need filter all rows in original `DataFrame` (also rows with not matched `kean-s`) then use:

```
df1 = emails[emails["X-Folder"].isin(williams["X-Folder"].value_counts().index[:10])]
```